# Composition of two diffeomorphisms

Tags: real-analysis

I need some assistance. Let be $U, V, W \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open sets, and $f \in \mathcal{C}^1(U, V)$ and $g \in \mathcal{C}^1(V,W)$ two diffeomorphisms. The goal is to show that the composition $g \circ f$ is a diffeomorphism too.

What I've tried so far? I assume that $g$ is the inverse function of $f$. Why? Because the domain of $g$ is equal to the codomain of $f$, i.e. $V$. We obtain $$(f^{-1} \circ f)(x) := f^{-1}(f(x)) = x =: \text{id}(x)$$

Using the chain rule, we differentiate both sides of the equality with respect to $x$ and get $$ \text{d} (f^{-1}(f(x))) \cdot \text{d} (f(x)) = 1 $$

It follows that $\text{d} (f(x)) \neq 0$ and this means that $\text{d} (f(x))$ have to be invertible. Is this correct so far?

Comment: I don't think it's correct.  You cannot assume $g$ is the inverse of $f$, what if $W\not=U$?

Comment: In fact if you *assume* $g$ is the inverse of $f$ then it's trivial to show that the composition is a diffeomorphism, because the composition is the identity function which is a diffeomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assume $g$ is the inverse of $f$ (if you could that would make the problem trivial).  You have to show $g\circ f$ satisfies the requirements to be a diffeomorphism.  In particular you have to show it is differentiable.

Comment: $f$ and $g$ are both of class $\mathcal{C}^1$, so they are differentiable. And compositions of differentiable functions are differentiable too. I don't see another way how to show it.

Comment: Yes that's pretty much all there is to it, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assume that $g$ is the inverse of $f$. As mentioned in another comment, assuming $W=U$ would not completely tackle the problem. I would proceed as follows:

The composition of smooth maps is smooth. By assumption, $f^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$ are both smooth. Moreover, $(g\circ f)^{-1}=f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$ . Therefore $g\circ f$ is a diffeomorphism.